# Custom subclassing issue

Tags: python

Considering this sample scenario:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import binascii
import cProfile
import re

class custom_str(str):
    __strip_non_hex = re.compile(r'^[^:]+:|[^0-9A-Fa-f]')

    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super(custom_str, cls).__new__(cls, value)

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, value):
        # creates a pure-hexadecimal string
        return cls(re.sub(cls.__strip_non_hex, '', value))

class custom_type(custom_str):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        # here I've to use custom_str.new()
        return super(custom_type, cls).__new__(cls, custom_str.new(value))

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, value):
        return cls('hex:%s' % (binascii.hexlify(value)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # tests
    v = custom_str('666f6f')
    assert v == '666f6f'
    assert type(v) == custom_str
    v = custom_str.new('66,6f,6f')
    assert v == '666f6f'
    assert type(v) == custom_str
    v = custom_type('hex:66,6f,6f')
    assert v == '666f6f'
    assert type(v) == custom_type
    v = custom_type.new('foo')
    assert v == '666f6f'
    assert type(v) == custom_type
    # profiling
    cProfile.run("custom_type.new('foo')", sort='call')
```

Code works, tests passes. I'm just wondering if I can avoid calling `custom_str.__new__()` twice.

If I change `custom_type.__new__()` to `return custom_str.new(value)` it works, but them it'll be of type `custom_str` instead of `custom_type`.

On other hand, if I change it to `return super(custom_type, cls).new(value)` it gets into infinite recursion.

Comment: Why is your construction logic so convoluted in the first place? Why does `custom_type` override `new` in a way that completely changes the meaning of the method?

Comment: @user2357112 `custom_type.__new__()` only works with well-formed data. In the sample I'm not validating anything, but in the real scenario it happens. `custom_type.new()`, on other hand, creates that well-formed data for a given user input. I've realized now that I gave a wrong example for `custom_type.new()`, I'll update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_strip_non_hex = re.compile(r'^[^:]+:|[^0-9A-Fa-f]')

def _strip(string):
    return re.sub(_strip_non_hex, '', value)

class custom_str(str):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, value):
        # creates a pure-hexadecimal string
        return custom_str.__new__(cls, _strip(value))

class custom_type(custom_str):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super(custom_type, cls).__new__(cls, _strip(value))

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, value):
        return cls('hex:%s' % (binascii.hexlify(value)))
```

Pull the non-hex-stripping logic out of `new` and into its own function to untangle the dependency graph.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, it really avoids calling the whole thing twice... With the actual code, which is a bit more complex, was difficult to reach that conclusion. Big thank you! :)